# Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let$f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.If$A \subseteq X$is bounded, then necessarily $f(A)$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, metric-spaces

Prove or disprove:

Is my solution correct? I assume that the statement is correct, but I'm not sure how to prove it:

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $A \subseteq X$ is bounded, then necessarily $f(A)$ is bounded.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Assume that $A \subseteq X$ is bounded. This means that there exists a constant $M$ such that for all $x, y \in A$, the metric $d(x, y) \leq M$.

Since $f$ is continuous, it implies that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x, y \in X$ with $d(x, y) < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$.

We aim to show that $f(A)$ is bounded. Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary real number. Since $A$ is bounded, there exists $x_0 \in X$ and $r > 0$ such that $A \subseteq B(x_0, r)$, where $B(x_0, r)$ denotes the open ball with radius $r$ around $x_0$.

Take $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta$ such that for all $x, y \in X$ with $d(x, y) < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$. Set $\varepsilon = 1$, then there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < 1$ for all $x, y \in X$ with $d(x, y) < \delta_1$.

Since $A \subseteq B(x_0, r)$, we can choose $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for all $x, y \in A$ with $d(x, y) < \delta_2$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \delta_1$.

Let $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$. Then for all $x, y \in A$ with $d(x, y) < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \delta_1$.

Now consider $f(A)$. Let $z \in f(A)$ be an arbitrary number, which means there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = z$. Since $A \subseteq B(x_0, r)$, there exists $b \in X$ such that $d(a, b) < \delta$. Thus, $|f(a) - f(b)| < \delta_1$.

We have:
[ |z - f(b)| = |f(a) - f(b)| < \delta_1 < 1. ]

This implies that $z - f(b) < 1$ and $f(b) - z < 1$. Therefore, $|f(b)| < |z| + 1$.

Since $z$ was an arbitrary number in $f(A)$, we have shown that $f(A)$ is bounded, as for any $z \in f(A)$, we have $|z| \leq |z| + 1$.

Thus, the claim is proved.

Comment: it seems to me that my proof is extremely complicated

Comment: For $f:X=(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=1/x$ and $A=X$ the set $A$ is bounded, but $f(A)=(1,\infty)$ is unbounded.

Comment: how do you know that $\delta_1 < 1$?